# Аргумент типа "WCHAR *" несовместим с параметром типа "const char *"

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
bool    cMemoryEdit::GetProcess()
{
    HANDLE hPID = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry;
    pEntry.dwSize = sizeof(pEntry);
    Process32First(hPID, &pEntry);
    do
        if (!strcmp(pEntry.szExeFile, ProcessName)) //аргумент типа "WCHAR *" несовместим с параметром типа "const char *"
        {
            dwPID = pEntry.th32ProcessID;
            CloseHandle(hPID);
            hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwPID);
            return true;
        }
   while (Process32Next(hPID, &pEntry));
   return false;
}
```

Прошу помощи)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool    cMemoryEdit::GetProcess()
{
    HANDLE hPID = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry;
    pEntry.dwSize = sizeof(pEntry);
    Process32First(hPID, &pEntry);
    do
        if (!wcscmp(pEntry.szExeFile, L"explorer.exe"))
        {
            dwPID = pEntry.th32ProcessID;
            CloseHandle(hPID);
            hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwPID);
            return true;
        }
   while (Process32Next(hPID, &pEntry));
   return false;
}
```

На сколько я знаю то strcmp - ищет совпадения между char* и char*, а pEntry.szExeFile TCHAR. Советую использовать как у меня выше.

Comment: Мне нужно с переменной ProcessName, она кстати char*

Comment: GetProcess(WCHAR* ProcessName) - bool будет принимать имя переменной. 
mbstowcs - с char* на wchar и так передавать